# Cannot use static class when placing a static constructor

Tags: c#, static-constructor

I have the following static class:

```
public static class UnitTestDefinitions
{
    public static int Foo = 4;

    /// <summary>
    ///     static constructor
    /// </summary>
    static UnitTestDefinitions()
    {
        InitAccounts();
    }

     private static void InitAccounts()
     {
         // some code
     }

     // more code
 }
```

I have a NUnit test that fails to run because I cannot access `Foo` :

[image]

The actual exception that I get is:

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233036   Message=The type initializer for
>   'Ublux.Communications.PrimaryService.UnitTestDefinitions' threw an
>   exception.   Source=Ublux.Communications.CoreService
>   TypeName=Ublux.Communications.PrimaryService.UnitTestDefinitions
>   StackTrace:
>          at Ublux.Communications.CoreService.UnitTests.TestCloudServicesCore.TestAuthentication()
>   in C:\GIT\Ublux\Ublux Communications Core
>   Service\Ublux.Communications.CoreService\Ublux.Communications.CoreService\UnitTests\TestCloudServices_Core.cs:line
>   146   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146233040
>          Message=Exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' was thrown.

**I been using c# for a while so to me it is obvious that the problem has to be in the static constructor, In other words there has to be a problem with the method `InitAccounts()`.**

---

Because of that I REMOVED the static constructor on the static class UnitTestDefinitions and call the `InitAccounts()` method manually as:

[image]

### When I do that I get no exception and everything works great why?

Comment: Just a note, the constructor is `UnitTestDefinitions()`, not the method `InitAccounts()` as you said. I assume this is typo.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can reasonably answer this; you're going to have to debug why that `InitAccounts` method failed when called from the .cctor; we can't tell you from a screenshot... possibly a race condition, possibly a re-entrant .cctor loop?

Comment: You used to invoke `InitAccounts` a lot earlier than now. If static constructors like this are a common thing in your application, there's any number of ordering issues that might cause it to fail. We can't really help you - the context of the problem is too large and quite impossible to narrow. You'll need to trace what the inner exception is and why it happens.

Comment: Though given that you're adding custom `AssemblyResolve` handler, that might be a good start - if `InitAccounts` requires that to be present, you'd get a failure. Static constructors are only guaranteed to run before you need them, not *right* before you need them - and in current .NET they usually run during JITting of the method, which is before any of this code (including assigning the handler) runs.

Comment: Note that most of the votes were for "Missing [MCVE]" - post clearly indicates that you know InitAccount is the problem but no code shown... Duplicate I picked just re-iterates "TypeInitializeException caused by previous failure to initialize class" - if you trying to clarify something else for yourself make sure to [edit] post with MCVE and clear explanation of what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program. If your `InitAccounts()` method is attempting to access objects that haven't been initialized yet, you may get an exception. Since you haven't provided that code, it's hard to say. This is one big reason for avoiding static classes altogether (use a Singleton if necessary).

Comment: Making the class a singleton fixed the problem. On the private constructor I placed the `InitAccounts()`method and everything works great now. To me it is the same code I do not understand why making it a singleton fixed the problem.